# Get User By Name Without Discriminator

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to find a user on the server by just the name giving by another user without the discriminator. I am adding a system to my bot that allows me to create user groups and it also adds a category and text/voice channels for them. I set a user as the "founder" and "leader" which allows them to add other users to the group. The problem is, the group is hidden to anyone not in the group, so they are not able to simply mention the user to add, but rather just have to use the persons username as they see it without the discriminator.

I have `message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.tag === newMemberName)` but it requires a tag with discriminator.

My entire method is

```
function addMember(message) {
    var server = message.guild;
    var user = message.author;
    var messageContent = message.content;
    var args = messageContent.substring(1).split(' ');
    var channel = message.channel.parent.name;
    var json = fs.readFileSync("allegiances.json");
    var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
    var currentChannel = message.channel.name.toLowerCase();
    if ((args[1] != null) && (currentChannel == "leadercommands")) {
        var userid = user.id;
        if (parsed[channel].leaders.includes(userid)) {
            var newMemberName = args[1];
            console.log(newMemberName);
            var newMember = server.members.cache.find(member => member.username === newMemberName);
            console.log(newMember);
            newMember.roles.add(server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === channel));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use [any `GuildMember` property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) in a `find()` function, including `member.user.username`

Comment: I just tried that way, and it still yields an undefined result. I have edited my post to include the entire method.

Comment: Remember that `username` isn't a property on `GuildMember`, only on `User`. `member.user.username`

Comment: So instead of member.username I should be using member.user.username?

Comment: Yeah, it would work.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still returns undefined using `server.members.cache.find(member => member.user.username === newMemberName)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
server.members.fetch({ query: args[1], limit: 1 }).then(user => {
            user.first().roles.add(server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === channel))
        }).catch(console.error);
```

I found this code allows you to find a user, or users if you want to get more than 1, by their name without the discriminator. All other systems used to find a user seem to require a discriminator to work.